# How to get subcategories from different store/storeviews by a specific main category

Tags: category, multistore

I like to do a cms page with all brands (subcategories) on it. We have a multistore wise set up. But at the moment, it shows me only subcategories and categories from one storeview.

I have this just copied and change the

->load(195);
->setStoreId(2)

But it seems that I need to do something else, as it shows me only from one store the list. See here:

https://www.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands/

Here is the code I use:

```
    <div class="main row">
<div class="col-main col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<?php
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(195);
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId(2)
        ->addFieldToFilter('level', ['lteq' => $parentCategory->getLevel() + 2])
        /*->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1)*/
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => '195'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => '136'))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(['name'])
        ->setOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
?>
<?php $previous = null;?>
<?php foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>

    <?php $name = $category->getName();
          $firstLetter = substr($name, 0, 1);
          if($previous == null){
             echo '<div class="col-sm-12">'."\n";
             echo '<h4 style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:2px;">'.$firstLetter.'</h4>'."\n";
             $previous = $firstLetter;
          }
          elseif ($previous !== $firstLetter){
                echo '</div>'."\n";
                echo '<div class="col-sm-12">'."\n";
                echo '<h4 style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:2px;">'.$firstLetter.'</h4>'."\n";
                $previous = $firstLetter;
          }
          echo '<a href="'.$category->getUrl().'" style="margin:10px">'.$category->getName().'</a>'."\n";

    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It not gives what I like to have. Here is the link from this page:

[link]https://www.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands/

I like to show on this CMS page from all storeviews (4 of them) all categories under a specific given category id.

so should be something similar to this:

```
ACTIVE / OUTDOOR / WORK

Cat 1 / Cat 11 / Cat 21
Cat 2 / Cat 12 / Cat 22
Cat 3 / Cat 13 / Cat 23
```

As Active, Outdoor and Work are the storeviews.

Comment: have you filter current store view categories right?

Comment: As I am new in Magento. I not really understand Your question.

When I put this part of code in one store view, I see all categories from it. If I use this code in another store (store view) I see it all those categories.

I only like to see all categories on a cms page, for all of the store views.

How I can filter current store view categories?

Comment: // Current store id 
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$BrandsCategoryName = 'Brands';
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $BrandsCategoryName);

if(count($categories) && $category = $categories->getFirstItem()) {
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
    foreach ($children as $category) {
          echo $category->getName(); // will return category name 
          echo $category->getRequestPath(); // will return category URL
    }
}
```

Comment: It not gives what I like to have. Here is the link from this page:

[link]https://www.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands/

I like to show on this CMS page from all storeviews (4 of them) all categories under a specific given category id.

so should be something similar to this:

ACTIVE                   OUTDOOR               WORK
Cat 1                       Cat 11                      Cat 21
Cat 2                       Cat 12                      Cat 22
Cat 3                       Cat 13                      Cat 23

As Active, Outdoor and Work are the storeviews.

Comment: need to display all subcategories and categories  to current store right?

Comment: yes, plus from all other stores too

Comment: but category  id "195" assigned all store?

Comment: can share your admin Manage Categories screen shot?

Comment: no, category id 195 is only for one store.

Here is the store view: http://www.samui-infotech.com/store_view.pdf

And here the category structure: http://www.samui-infotech.com/ct_id.pdf

Comment: your going wrong way

Comment: you need display brands sub categories per store right?

Comment: yes, exactly. Okay. If i go the wrong way... how I can do it better?

Comment: I updated ans pls see

Comment: I put it as it is in the phtml file...

It shows me now: Brandsbrands.htmlActivityactivity.htmlWomenswomens.htmlMensmens.htmlChildrenschildrens.htmlAccessoriesaccessories.html

what we have here in the navigation: https://www.outdoorequipped.com/home/allbrands/